# How to resolve RuntimeError: await wasn't used with future using aiohttp and asyncio in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I made some pretty simple script which pulls data from clicky.com api but for some reason it does not work as expected from time to time.

Sometimes it gets results but another time I am getting the following errors which I cant debug. I am fairly new to asyncio and aiohttp

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/almeco/Downloads/python/_projekty/projekt_baza_review/1_stable/asy/usable/baza_goals.py", line 118, in <module>
    goals_results_last_week = asyncio.run(goals_clicky_results_last_week())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/almeco/Downloads/python/_projekty/projekt_baza_review/1_stable/asy/usable/baza_goals.py", line 82, in goals_clicky_results_last_week
    responses_clicky_goals = await asyncio.gather(*tasks_goals)
  File "/Users/almeco/Downloads/python/_projekty/projekt_baza_review/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1122, in send
    return self._coro.send(arg)
  File "/Users/almeco/Downloads/python/_projekty/projekt_baza_review/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 535, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/Users/almeco/Downloads/python/_projekty/projekt_baza_review/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 542, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Users/almeco/Downloads/python/_projekty/projekt_baza_review/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 907, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Users/almeco/Downloads/python/_projekty/projekt_baza_review/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1175, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/Users/almeco/Downloads/python/_projekty/projekt_baza_review/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 986, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[return-value]  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1040, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 954, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 502, in sock_connect
    return await fut
RuntimeError: await wasn't used with future
```

How to debug this? Whats the problem here?

edited:
Here is my code for you to test:

```
import asyncio
import datetime

import aiohttp
import requests


start_operacji = datetime.datetime.now()
print('start', start_operacji)


date_filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m_%H-%M')

def goals_clicky_tasks_last_week(session):
    tasks_clicky_goals = []
    # todo to mozna by jeszcze dać do asyncio
    clicky_auth = requests.get(
        'https://api.clicky.com/api/account/sites?username=meeffe&password=hAs!23$5cy&output=json')
    auth_jsonised = clicky_auth.json()

    list_site_id_sitekey_dict = []

    for k in auth_jsonised:
        site_id_sitekey_dict = {'site_id': k['site_id'], 'sitekey': k['sitekey']}
        list_site_id_sitekey_dict.append(site_id_sitekey_dict)

    for auth_item in list_site_id_sitekey_dict:
        goal_url = f"https://api.clicky.com/api/stats/4?site_id={auth_item['site_id']}&sitekey={auth_item['sitekey']}&type=goals&date=today&limit=1000&output=json"
        tasks_clicky_goals.append(asyncio.ensure_future(session.get(goal_url, ssl=False)))

    return tasks_clicky_goals


async def goals_clicky_results_last_week():
    list_final_goals = []

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:

        tasks_goals = goals_clicky_tasks_last_week(session)

        responses_clicky_goals = await asyncio.gather(*tasks_goals)

        for response_clicky_goal in responses_clicky_goals:

            clicky_data = await response_clicky_goal.json(content_type=None)

            goals_list = []
            for url_item_goal in clicky_data[0]['dates'][0]['items']:
                if url_item_goal['conversion'] != '':
                    if url_item_goal['title'].startswith(
                            'http'):  # nie bierze pod uwagę goalsów które zawierają U - https:// etc
                        goals_dict = {'url': url_item_goal['title'].replace('http://', 'https://'),
                                      'goals': url_item_goal['value'],
                                      'ad_ctr': url_item_goal['conversion']
                                      }
                        goals_list.append(goals_dict)
                    else:
                        continue
                else:
                    continue

            list_final_goals.append(goals_list)

    flattened_list_final_goals = [val for sublist in list_final_goals for val in sublist]

    return flattened_list_final_goals

print(asyncio.run(goals_clicky_results_last_week()), 'goals_clicky_results_last_week')
goals_results_last_week = asyncio.run(goals_clicky_results_last_week())


######################################################################



end = datetime.datetime.now() - start_operacji

print('Ready:)!')
print('It took: ', end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution by myself.

1. Instead of aiohttp I used httpx
2. I used timeout with every request
3. I removed unnecessary await

Changes in an original code below. Now the script run 100% stable. To be frank I am not sure which of these changes had the biggest impact but it works as expected.

```
timeout = httpx.Timeout(60.0, connect=60.0)

async with httpx.AsyncClient(verify=False, timeout=timeout) as session:

        tasks_goals = goals_clicky_tasks_last_week(session)

        responses_clicky_goals = await asyncio.gather(*tasks_goals)

        for response_clicky_goal in responses_clicky_goals:

            clicky_data = response_clicky_goal.json()
   ...
```